# Finite-dimensional Hilbert $C^*$-modules

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, hilbert-spaces, noncommutative-geometry

Does there exist a classification, or characterization, of finite-dimensional Hilbert $C^*$-modules? More generally, does there exist a characterization of countable direct sums of finite-dimensional Hilbert $C^*$-modules

Edit: By finite dimensional I mean that the $C^*$-module is finite dimensional as a vector space.

Comment: Do you mean finite dimensional as a vector space, or some notion of dimension as a right module (over the $C^*$ algebra in question)

Comment: as a vector space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a vector space, okay.  Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $E$ a Hilbert module over $A$ which is finite dimensional as a vector space. Then $A$ acts by left multiplication on $E$, i.e., we have a bounded homomorphism from $A$ into $B(E) \cong M_n$. Letting $I$ be the kernel of this homomorphism, this shows that $A$ has a finite codimension closed ideal $I$ (which is automatically self-adjoint) and $E$ is a Hilbert module over $A/I$ (exercise).

So we have to classify finite dimensional Hilbert modules over finite dimensional C*-algebras. Any finite dimensional C*-algebra is a direct sum of matrix algebras, and any Hilbert module over such a direct sum decomposes as a direct sum of Hilbert modules over the summand matrix algebras. So we only have to classify the finite dimensional Hilbert modules over $M_n$. But again, left multiplication gives a homomorphism from $M_n$ into $B(E)$, and this $*$-homomorphism must be unital (exercise), which by the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32511/homomorphisms-between-matrix-algebras) means that $E \cong \mathbb{C}^n\otimes \mathbb{C}^k$ for some $k$, with the action being $a(v\otimes w) = av\otimes w$. So $E$ is a direct sum of finitely many copies of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a module over $M_n$ in the natural way. The inner product is described in Matthew's answer.

Comment: I interpreted the question to be about right Hilbert $C^*$-modules.  Is it obvious that you get a $*$-homomorphism?  I couldn't quite immediately see this...

Comment: I guess for right modules you multiply on the right, so it's a homomorphism from $A^{op}$, isn't that right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase my question well: it was the star bit which bothered me.  So $E$ is finite dimensional and so has an algebraic basis, and so $B(E) \cong M_n$.  However, it is obvious that we can pick this basis so the (left, say) action gives a $*$-homomorphism to $M_n$?  I couldn't see this...

Comment: I just posted an answer which gives a different answer.  For example, for the 2nd part of your answer...  What if I let $E=\mathbb C^n$ with (left) action of $M_n$ the usual action given by treating $\mathbb C^n$ as column vectors, and with $E$ having the $M_n$-valued inner product $(\xi|\eta) = \theta_{\xi,\eta}$ the rank-one operator $\alpha \mapsto (\alpha|\eta)\xi$.  This seems to me to be a (left) Hilbert $C^*$-module over $M_n$ which isn't of your form.

Comment: @MatthewDaws: good point about $*$-homomorphisms.  I think my argument is (farily easily) fixable, but please check it.  The example you mention isn't of the type I describe, but that is only because there is a typo in my description ($M_n$ for $\mathbb{C}^n$).  Fixing it now.

Comment: On second thoughts, I have to do more work to fix the last part. Since you have a clean answer I think I'll just delete this one.

Comment: Huh, apparently you can't delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Let $E$ be a [Hilbert $C^*$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_C*-module) over a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$.  (I'll use the right module convention, which basically just makes life difficult for myself.)  Then $I$, the closure of $\newcommand{\lin}{\operatorname{lin}} \lin \{ (x|y):x,t\in E \}$ is a (two-sided) closed ideal in $A$.  (Because, for example $(x|y)a = (x|y\cdot a)\in I$).  Recall that $E$ is *full* when $A=I$.

Now suppose that $E$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.  Then $\lin \{ (x|y):x,y\in E \}$ is finite-dimensional, so equals $I$.  As $I$ is itself a $C^\ast$-algebra, and is finite-dimensional, it in particular has a unit $e$.  Then $I = eA = Ae = AeA$ and $A\rightarrow I, a\mapsto ae = eae = ea$ is a $*$-homomorphism which is the identity on $I$.  It follows that $A \cong I \oplus B$ for some $C^\ast$-algebra $B$.

We know that $E = E\cdot I$ and so $x = x\cdot e$ for each $x\in E$.  We can hence treat $E$ is a *full* Hilbert $C^\ast$-module over $I$.  We now use that $I$ is a direct sum of matrix algebras, say $I = \sum_{k=1}^N M_{n_k}$.  Let $1_k$ be the unit of $M_{n_k}$ so $x = x\cdot e = x\cdot(\sum 1_k) = \sum_k x\cdot 1_k$ for $x\in E$, and so $E = \sum_{k=1}^N E_k$ where $E_k = E\cdot 1_k$ is a *full* module over $M_{n_k}$.

Finally, we classify modules $F$ over $M_n$.  One can show (I do not know a fast way to show this) that if $F$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with a (left) action of $M_n$ then $F \cong \mathbb C^n \otimes F'$ where $M_n$ acts on $\mathbb C^n$ in the usual way (treat $\mathbb C^n$ as column vectors) and the action on $F$ is as $a\otimes 1$.  As $F$ is a right module over $M_n$, we have that $(\xi\otimes x')\cdot a = a^\top\xi \otimes x'$ where $a^\top$ is the transpose of $a\in M_n$.  Let $\delta=\delta_1$ be the first unit vector in the standard basis of $\mathbb C^n$, so $a^\top\delta\otimes x'$ is a typical elementary vector in $F$.

Now consider the $M_n$-valued inner-product on $F$ which is
$$
(a^\top\delta\otimes x'|b^\top\delta\otimes y') = a^\ast (\delta\otimes x'|
\delta\otimes y') b = a^\ast \theta(x'|y')b
$$
say, for some sesquilinear $\theta:F\times F\rightarrow M_n$.  However, notice that if $a^\top\delta=0$ or $b^\top\delta=0$ then $a^*\theta(x'|y')b=0$ for any $x',y'$.  Let $\theta_{\xi,\eta}\in M_n$ be the rank-one operator $\alpha\mapsto \xi(\eta|\alpha)$.  Further let $J:\mathbb C^n\rightarrow \mathbb C^n$ be the anti-linear operator given by pointwise complex conjugation.  Then $a^\top = Ja^\ast J$.  Thus, if $(\xi|\delta)=0$ or $(\eta|\delta)=0$, then $\theta_{\xi,\alpha}^\ast \theta(x',y') \theta_{\eta,\beta}=0$ for any $\alpha,\beta$, so $(\xi|\theta(x',y')\eta)=0$.  It follows that $\theta(x',y') \in \mathbb C \theta_{\delta,\delta}$.  So, there is a Hilbert space structure on $F'$ with $\theta(x',y') = (x'|y') \theta_{\delta,\delta}$.  We conclude that the $M_n$-valued inner-product on $F=\mathbb C^n\otimes F'$ is
$$ (\xi\otimes x'|\eta\otimes y') = (x'|y') \theta_{\eta,\xi} \in M_n. $$

So, this completely answers the case of a finite-dimensional module over $A$.  There was also the question of countable direct sums of such things.  I'm not sure what is meant here.  If you know that $E$ is a countable direct sum $E\cong \oplus E_n$ each $E_n$ finite-dimensional, then you can piece together the structure for each $E_n$.  However, if you want to know *which* $E$ can occur in this way, then that seems more complicated.

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for the following fact: "if $F$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with a (left) action of $M_n$ then F≅Cn⊗F′ where $M_n$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^n$ in the usual way (treat $\mathbb{C}^n$ as column vectors) and the action on $F$ is as a⊗1".

Comment: I also have another question if it doesn't bother you: how do you use the "full module" condition after you establish it for the $E_k$'s?

Comment: @JeyromeSapin I probably don't use that each $E_k$ is full.  I think I just used the "full" condition to reduce to the matrix algebra case.  I'm afraid I don't know a reference, off the top of my head.